# Have forms pop up in same spot each time

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I've been looking around for this answer but can't seem to find it.  I'm running VS2012 with VB.Net and have a multi-form application.  As the forms open, they always appear in different spots, almost cascading down the screen if I were to have them all open at once.  How can I make them always appear centered?

For example:

```
Form1.ShowDialog()
```

This should be in the center of the screen, and appear there every time it is opened.

Comment: Set this in the properties for each form... Windows start position will do it

Comment: I have a followup question for you guys..
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61613124/is-there-a-way-to-get-windows-to-ignore-the-manual-windowstartuplocation-im-usi

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try:

```
Form1.StartupPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen
Form1.ShowDialog()
```

Answer (score -2):

Form.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;

Comment: Please explain how the very small difference to the existing answer is relevant and what advantage it has.